# MS Word - add a character after bold

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, formatting, wildcards

I have a number of lines like that:

> **wykluczenie** expulsion, disqualification, exclusion
>   **wykluczenie wspólnika** expulsion of a partner, disqualification of a partner
>   **wykładnia** explanation, clarification, interpretation, construction

I want to add `=` (equals) character after bold elements, ie. a wildcard that will find bold text, leave it intact, add = (equals) character, then keep the rest of the line intact.
E.g.,

> **wykluczenie**= expulsion, disqualification, exclusion
>   **wykluczenie wspólnika**= expulsion of a partner, disqualification of a partner
>   **wykładnia**= explanation, clarification, interpretation, construction

It will be used to create a termbase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- open "find and replace" (CTRL+H)
- select "find what" box

  - in format - font: select "bold" => you'll see "font: Bold" under find what
- in "replace with" enter `^&=`
- press "replace all"

[image]

Note: it'll insert also `=` as bold, if you specify it not to be bold, then original bold text will also be converted. If you really need it not bold, then need to do another find and replace, replacing bold `=` to non-bold `=`.